# Creating shortcut to console application in NSIS with particular font

Tags: nsis

I have an NSIS script which can create a shortcut to an application with `CreateShortCut`.

The application that the shortcut points to is a console application, but one which works much better if there is something other than the default font chosen.  Of course, the user can be told to follow instructions like https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/change-font-and-font-size-in-windows-10-command-prompt.html  to change to a different font on the shortcut, but my quetsion is whether that can be automated in NSIS?  That is, check if a particular font is available and then have the shortcut start a console with that font.

If that is impossible in NSIS for a particular shortcut, is there a way to give users the option to have a system-wide change to the font used in all terminals?

Answer (score 1):

The `CreateShortcut` instruction only supports basic shortcut properties, it does not support [console properties](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130527-00/?p=4253) set by `IShellLinkDataList`.

Setting the [`NT_CONSOLE_PROPS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/ns-shlobj_core-nt_console_props) data has two issues:

- It is all or nothing, you have to set the size, color and edit options in addition to the font.
- Ideally you should provide the "index of the font in the system's console font table" but that index is not really documented and I don't know how to map from a font name to the index.

If you still want to do it then you must use the System plug-in:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include Win\COM.nsh ; NSIS v3
!define /ifndef LF_FACESIZE 32
!define /ifndef NT_CONSOLE_PROPS_SIG 0xA0000002

Section

StrCpy $R1 "$Desktop\MyApp.lnk" ; .Lnk path
StrCpy $R3 "Consolas" ; Font name
StrCpy $R5 i0x36 ; tmPitchAndFamily?
StrCpy $R6 400 ; "The weight can range from 100 to 1000, in multiples of 100. For example, the normal weight is 400, while 700 is bold"
StrCpy $R7 0xc0000 ; dwFontSize packed COORD
StrCpy $R8 0x200060 ; dwWindowSize packed COORD

System::Call '*(&l4,i${NT_CONSOLE_PROPS_SIG}, i0xf50007,i0x3e70050,i$R8,i0x0,i0x0,i0x0,i$R7,i$R5,i$R6, &w${LF_FACESIZE}"$R3", i0x19,i0x0,i0x1,i0x1,i0x1,i0x32,i0x4,i0x1,i0x0,i0x800000,i0x8000,i0x808000,i0x80,i0x800080,i0x8080,i0xc0c0c0,i0x808080,i0xff0000,i0xff00,i0xffff00,i0xff,i0xff00ff,i0xffff,i0xffffff)p.R2'

!insertmacro ComHlpr_CreateInProcInstance ${CLSID_ShellLink} ${IID_IShellLink} r0 ""
${If} $0 P<> 0
    ${IShellLink::SetPath} $0 '("%COMSPEC%").r1'
    ${IShellLink::SetArguments} $0 '("/k echo HelloWorld").r2'
    ${If} $1 = 0
    ${AndIf} $2 = 0
        ${IUnknown::QueryInterface} $0 '("${IID_IShellLinkDataList}",.r1)'
        ${If} $1 P<> 0
            ${IShellLinkDataList::AddDataBlock} $1 '(pR2).r2'
            ${IUnknown::Release} $1 ""
        ${EndIf}
        ${IUnknown::QueryInterface} $0 '("${IID_IPersistFile}",.r1)'
        ${If} $1 P<> 0
            ${IPersistFile::Save} $1 '("$R1",1).r2'
            ${IUnknown::Release} $1 ""
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
    ${IUnknown::Release} $0 ""
${EndIf}
System::Free $R2 ; Free NT_CONSOLE_PROPS

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!